# Check Data type for a serialized object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 classes (Client, Admin) that inherit from the same parent class (User).

Those 3 classes implement the NSCoding protocol so I can store them in the userdefaults as Data.

When my application starts I want to deserialized the stored Data into Swift 
objects.

Is there a way to know which type the stored Data belongs to?

something like this:

```
let data = defaults.object(forKey: "loggedInUser") as? Data
if data is Client
     let client = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? Client
if data is Admin
     let admin = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? Admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check

```
if let data = defaults.object(forKey: "loggedInUser") as? Data {
    let obj = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data)

    if obj is Client {
        let client = obj as! Client
    }

    if obj is Admin {
        let admin = obj as! Admin
    }
}
```

Comment: Why optionals? If `obj` passes the check, it is 100% this type and you can safely unwrap it.

Comment: That's not what I mean and this code is not about failable `String` or `URL` initializers. If `obj is Client`, it is guaranteed to be not `nil` and you can safely write `let client = obj as! Client`

Comment: Oh, sorry! I answered wrong question. Ah, yes. You are right! We can write `let client = obj as! Client`. Let me update the answer. Thank you so much!